# Finding discontinuities from a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is probably a quite simple solution to my problem, but I'm having great touble formulating a good search phrase for it. I have a table containing timestamps and counts:

```
2013-08-15 14:43:58.447    5
2013-08-15 14:44:58.307    12
2013-08-15 14:45:58.383    14
2013-08-15 14:46:58.180    0
2013-08-15 14:47:58.210    4
2013-08-15 14:48:58.287    6
2013-08-15 14:49:58.550    12
2013-08-15 14:50:58.440    2
2013-08-15 14:51:58.390    5
```

As you can see, the count increases and then gets emptied once in a while. Searching for the rows where count = 0 is easy, but sometimes the count is increased before the zero count has been logged. At 14:49 the count is 12, it is then reset to 0 and incremented to 2 before the next log at 14:50.

I need to list the timestamps where the count is less than the count before:

```
2013-08-15 14:46:58.180    0
2013-08-15 14:50:58.440    2
```

I started to make a join on the table itself, to compare two rows but the SQL soon got very messy.

Comment: If you can put them in a table with an index in the right order, the join should be very simple.

Comment: The table is indexed on the timestamp, but I can't really see the simple solution.

Comment: Add a table where line 1 has number 1 and line 2 has number 2 etc. Then you can just select where `T2.id = T1.id+1` and `T2.num<T1.num`

Comment: This question may be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/there-is-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also in this case you can use [LEAD()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function:

```
with CTE as
(
select t.*, LEAD(ct) OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) as LEAD_CT from t
)  
select dt,ct from CTE where LEAD_CT>CT
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3385f/4)

UPD: [LEAD()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) is available from version SQLServer 2012. In 2008 you can replace it with a subquery:

```
select *
      FROM T as T1
      where (SELECT TOP 1 ct FROM T 
                             WHERE T.dt<T1.DT
                             ORDER BY dt DESC) >CT
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3385f/3)

Comment: Not in SQL 2008 you can't.

Comment: But, nevertheless, a nice feature to have in MSSQL2012! Thanks for showing us anyway. ;-)

Comment: @podiluska: You're right. Sorry I've missed "sql-server-2008" tag :(

Comment: Too bad I'm stuck with 2008, since this was a nice clean solution.

Comment: @Anlo I've added the query version for 2008 server.

Comment: Wow... I expected a subquery to be slower than podiluska's and Nenad Zivkovic's suggestions. Checking the execution plans on my 200k row table, the query cost came out as 1:11 in favor of the subquery version. Note to self, NEVER guess which query will run faster...

Answer (score 11):

What this does is it creates a row number based on the ts (datetime) column, then it is easier to join to the previous entry. It then compares the times and the counts to find the exceptions.

```
;with cte as 
(
    select * ,
      ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ts) rn    
    from yourtable
)
    select c1.* from cte c1
        inner join cte c2
            on c1.rn=c2.rn+1
            and c1.c < c2.c
```

Comment: I would actually not compare the ts and instead add count as a second sort argument (decreasing)  as one could consider 2 count values at the same ts an anomaly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function you can assign numbers on your order and use them for join:

```
WITH CTE_RN AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) RN
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT r2.* 
FROM CTE_RN r1
    INNER JOIN CTE_RN r2 ON r1.RN +1 = r2.RN
WHERE r1.count > r2.count
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/907a3/2)**