# Calculate Percent Difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two months with two values, for example:

```
July-2013  1838.08
Aug-2013   3500.08
```

How can I calculate the percentage difference in August compared with July?

Comment: Do you really want the statistical *Variance* of two numbers?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I would like to calculate the percentage that was increase/decrease compared to previous month

Comment: Ah, that is called "*percentage difference*".  "Variance" is an entirely different thing.

Comment: I didn't said Variance

Comment: Your original post and title did say "Variance" (I just checked the Edit log to be sure).

Comment: sorry :), you are right, any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The formula for this is easy it's `(Curr-Prev)*100.0/Prev`, what's not clear is how to apply it since we do not know your table definition, contents or keys, and thus do not know how to generically select one month and it's previous value.  But, hard-coding it would be like this:

```
SELECT  
    100.0*(curr.Val - prev.Val) / prev.Val As PercentDiff
FROM yourTable As curr
JOIN yourTable As prev
    ON  curr.MonthStr = 'Aug-2013' AND prev.MonthStr = 'July-2013'
```

Comment: Would this be able to be used in a dynamic sense?

Comment: LAG function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement

Answer (score 3):

The problem with working out percentage changes is that you need to be careful of when the 'old value' is 0 or you will get an error.

One approach is using nullif(old_Value, 0) but then the problem with that is when old values are 0 you are asking for New_Value/NULL which is the new value. (definitely not the % change)

I worked around it like this:

```
(case
            when
                OldValue = 0 and NewValue = 0
            then
                cast(0 as Decimal(10,2))
            when
                OldValue = 0
            then
                'Na'
            else
                cast(cast(
                            (
                                (
                                    (cast(NewValue as decimal(11,3)) - 
                                     cast(OldValue as decimal(11,3))
                                    )*100
                                )/cast(OldValue as decimal(11,3))
                            ) as decimal(20,3)
                         ) as varchar
                    )

            end) '% Change'
```

I probably threw a lot more casts than necessary but it works well for me. Gives Na when necessary and 0 when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT VAR(Bonus) 'Variance',
STDEVP(Bonus) 'Standard Deviation',
STDEV(Bonus) 'Standard Deviation',
VARP(Bonus) 'Variance for the Population'
FROM Sales.SalesPerson;
```

giving credit to fololwing post

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/20/sql-server-introduction-to-statistical-functions-var-stdevp-stdev-varp/

Comment: Note: clarification has changed the question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung .. you are right but what we can do .. i upvoted your comment

Answer (score 0):

to handle zeroes in the denominator, i use:

```
case 
  when oldVal<>0 then ((newVal-oldVal)*100.0)/oldVal 
  else 
    case when newVal=0 then 0 else Null end 
end
```

this will return 0 if newVal and oldVal are both 0, and Null if oldVal is zero but newVal is non-zero.

multiplying by 100.0 (as opposed to 100) will implicitly convert int fields into decimal.  i find it cleaner than try_convert().