# Subtract values on column "cantidad"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to subtract (cantidad 1 - cantidad 0) (cantidad 2 - 1 cantidad) (cantidad 3 - cantidad 2) for each line (that is my key field).

My SQL:

```
SELECT linea, producto, cantidad, operario, fecha 
FROM registro_cantidad_producida
```

Current Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "cantidad0", "cantidad1" and "cantidad2"? I don't see those columns.

Comment: How do you ensure that the order is correct? You don't have an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to access the "previous row" value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement)

Comment: @TheImpaler for example cantidad 0 = 0, cantidad 1 = 2342, cantidad 2 = 3855, cantidad 3 = 4608. etc.

Comment: @JDB I forgot to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to calculate the previous result:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce( t.cantid -
                 (select t2.cantid
                  from t t2
                  where t2.linea = t.linea and t2.fecha < t2.fecha
                  order by t2.fecha desc
                  limit 1
                 ),
                 t.cantid
                )
from t;
```