# Calculate Percentage Difference/Variance Between Rows - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good afternoon,

I am trying to calculate the percentage difference between rows in SQL Server and need help achieving this.

I want to compare the value from [Record_Count] with the previous value from [Record_Count] and **then calculate the variance in Percentage** between the 2 [Record_Count] Numbers. The below table is an example of the data.

So for example I would want to compare the value in row 268 with the value in row 267 and calculate the % increase/decrease and then compare row 269 with 268 and so on.

| ID | Record_Count | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 270 | 543 |  |
| 269 | 28361 |  |
| 268 | 548 |  |
| 267 | 28464 |  |

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated as I'm currently unsure on how to achieve this.

Comment: look at analytical functions involving lead/lag. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  These functions allow you to look ahead or behind rows based on an order such as your ID and get a value (such as your record_count) and compare it to values on the row from which it is being led or lagged.  An alternative way to do this is join based on ID + or -1 assuming a 1 variance always. or use min/max and a where clause.  but lead/lag is much simpler provided your version of SQL-server supports it.  In both cases: then do then do the math.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access the “previous row” value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Example so

```
with q (ID, Record_Count, Record_Count_Prev) as (
select ID, Record_Count, lag(Record_Count) over(order by ID), 
from [Your_table]
order by ID
)
select ID, Record_Count, Record_Count_Prev, case when isnull(Record_Count_Prev, 0) <> 0 then Record_Count / Record_Count_Prev else 0 end
from q;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
   , (1 - LEAD(Record_Count,1,Record_Count) over (order by id desc)/Record_Count) * 100  as chanegpercentage
from tablename
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Window `ROW_NUMBER()` function to access the next rows and compare columns.

```
With CTE AS(
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS seq
FROM variansTB
)
SELECT ID,Record_Count,
    ISNULL((SELECT Record_Count FROM CTE c WHERE c.seq = CTE.seq + 1),0)/Record_Count * 100 AS Variance
FROM CTE
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=951a906811092402a795069088735866)