# How to delete duplicates data that is in between two common value?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

How can I delete duplicate data based on the **common value (Start and End)**

***(Time is unique key)***

***My table is:***

| Time | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 10:24:11 | Start |
| **10:24:12** | **Result** |
| **10:24:13** | **Result** |
| 10:24:14 | End |
| 10:24:15 | Start |
| 10:24:16 | Result |
| 10:24:17 | End |

I want to get **Data: Result** in between Start and End that is with the MAX(TIME) when duplication does occur. as such

***The result that I want:***

| Time | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 10:24:11 | Start |
| **10:24:13** | **Result** |
| 10:24:14 | End |
| 10:24:15 | Start |
| 10:24:16 | Result |
| 10:24:17 | End |

I have tried rearranging the data, but couldn't seems to get the result that I want, Could someone give their advice on this case?

---

**Update**

I ended up not using either of the the approach suggested by @fredt and @airliquide as my version of HSQLDB doesn't support the function.

so what I did was, adding sequence and making Start = 1, Result = 2, and End = 3.

| Sequence | Time | Data | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:24:11 | Start | 1 |
| 2 | **10:24:12** | **Result** | 2 |
| 3 | **10:24:13** | **Result** | 2 |
| 4 | 10:24:14 | End | 3 |
| 5 | 10:24:15 | Start | 1 |
| 6 | 10:24:16 | Result | 2 |
| 7 | 10:24:17 | End | 3 |

Thereon, I make use of the indicator and sequence to get only latest Result. Such that if previous row is 2 (which is result), remove it.

The guide that I follow:
From: [Is there a way to access the "previous row" value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement)

```
select t1.value - t2.value from table t1, table t2 
where t1.primaryKey = t2.primaryKey - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi a first approach will be to use a lead function as folow

```
 select hour,status from (select *,lead(status,1) over ( order by hour) as lead
from newtable)compare 
where compare.lead <> status
OR lead is null
```

Give me what's expected using a postgres engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing with SQL procedures.

```
-- create the table with only two columns
CREATE TABLE actions (attime TIME UNIQUE, data VARCHAR(10));

-- drop the procedure if it exists
DROP PROCEDURE del_duplicates IF EXISTS;

create procedure del_duplicates()  MODIFIES SQL DATA begin atomic
DECLARE last_time time(0) default null;
 for_loop:
 -- loop over the rows in order
 FOR SELECT * FROM actions ORDER BY attime DO

  -- each time 'Start' is found, clear the last_time variable
  IF data = 'Start' THEN
   SET last_time = NULL; 
   ITERATE for_loop;
  END IF;

  -- each time 'Result' is found, delete the row with previous time
  -- if last_time is null, no row is actually deleted 
  IF data = 'Result' THEN
   DELETE FROM actions WHERE attime = last_time;
   -- then store the latest time
   SET last_time = attime; 
   ITERATE for_loop;
  END IF;
        
END FOR;        
END
```

Your data must all belong to a single day, otherwise there will be strange overlaps that cannot be distinguished. It is better to use TIMESTAMP instead of TIME.