# Creating a column that'll show previous rates

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd, datahistory

I'm creating a column that will show an old address. Whenever an address is updated the old address is expired the day before the new one is supposed to take effect and a new row with the same account number will be added with the new address (ex: old address will show: From: 10/01/2020 To: 12/31/2021 and the new address From: 01/01/2022 To: 12-31-9999). I'm trying to show old and new address side by side for each account number in SQL, but I'm getting zeros.

Sample Data

| AccountNumber | Address | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4895626 | 720 Main | 10/01/2020 | 12/31/2021 |
| 9794651 | 158 4th St | 09/29/2002 | 12/19/2020 |
| 4895626 | 5986 9th Ave | 01/01/2022 | 12/31/9999 |

Desired Results

| AccountNumber | Address | ValidFrom | ValidTo | PreviousAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4895626 | 720 Main | 10/01/2020 | 12/31/2021 | 0 |
| 9794651 | 158 4th St | 09/29/2002 | 12/19/2020 | 0 |
| 4895626 | 5986 9th Ave | 01/01/2022 | 12/31/9999 | 720 Main |

```
DECLARE @PreviousValidTo DATE;
SELECT @PreviousValidTo = DATEADD(DAY, -1, Z.ValidFrom)
FROM Address.NewAddress Z
SELECT Address, ValidFrom, ValidTo
CASE
            WHEN @PreviousValidTo = C.ValidFrom
            THEN C.Address
            ELSE 0
            END AS PreviousAddress
FROM Address.NewAddress C
```

Comment: Your first *select* will assign essentially a random value to `PreviousValidTo`, probably that's not your intention?  Your second query is not valid, where is `C`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Can you add the table definition, sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sorry about that, first timer. I've added some sample data and what I am trying to produce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access the "previous row" value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you could use `lag`

```
select *,
  Lag(address,1,'0') over(partition by accountnumber order by validto) PreviousAddress
from address.NewAddress
```

Comment: woooooow, I had tried LAG but didn't get anywhere. I've been stuck on this for far too long. Thank you!

Comment: quick question, I have multiple tables in this query and the LAG function seems to be referring to the table as a whole rather than the ADDRESS table. What could be causing the issue?