# Difference between values with same ID's between selected date and previous days date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem I have whereby I need to display the difference in values from the same column which has the same IDs, between selected date and selected date - 1 taking business days into account.

I have a sample below of what the data would look like in the database

```
ID   ValuationDate  Value
=========================
317  07/04/2022     3456
246  07/04/2022     851
317  06/04/2022     2987
246  06/04/2022     853
```

and the desired output would be

```
ID   Difference
==============
317   469
246   -2
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried multiple YouTube videos as well as trying to use `lag` function, unfortunately, my SQL skills are rather raw.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I will do as you have mentioned and try my best to correct the initial post

Comment: is pair (id, ValuationDate) unique?

Comment: Exactly what do You mean by "taking business days in to account"?

Comment: @smvenk yes, the pair is unique

Comment: Relevant: [Is there a way to access the "previous row" value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement) Sounds like you just need `LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ValuationDate)`

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Query for UNIQUE(id, ValuationDate)

SELECT id
     , ISNULL(ct1.Value - ct2.Value, 0) Difference -- isnull(...,0) - if no previous value 
  FROM <Current table> ct1
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN <Current table> ct2
    ON ct1.id = ct2.id
    and DATEDIFF(day, ct2.ValuationDate,ct1.ValuationDate) = 1
```

Comment: Oh wow, this exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help. I am so appreciative. I tried to upvote your answer, but am unable to.